# Assign a variable in curl URL shell script

Tags: bash, shell, api, csv, curl

I am trying to loop through the cells in a column in a csv file and assign each cell as a variable. I then want to take that variable and put it in a URL so it puts the cell from the csv in the url. When I run the script, it gives the error: "curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL"

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,

cat /Users/User/Desktop/hardwares_2018-01-23_11-02-05.csv | while read id



temp=`echo $id | sed 's/"//g'`
#echo $temp

do

curl -H "X-Application-Authorization: Bearer Token" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.application.v2.1+xml' -X DELETE https://api.application.com/hardwares/${temp}.xml



done
```

My csv file looks like this

```
1945603
1945604
1945605
1945606
1945607
1945608
1945609
1945610
1945611
1945612
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking us to find in your example ?

Comment: I have made the edit, I apologize. I am getting the error: curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL when I run the script

Comment: Read how to use `while loop` in `bash`. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: I am able to get it to loop through the id's when I un-hash echo $temp. I believe the error may be somewhere in the curl part of the script. I'm not sure how to assign the variable there. I may completely missing the point/mark there, and I apologize if I am.

Comment: I have added an answer, but I have no way to test its validity. Please use `cmdline` before running the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the first headr `-H` flag. It has white space in the string which might be getting interpreted as another argument to `curl`.

Here I made some generic modification to the script. I don't have an environment to test it. Hope it helps.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

h1flag="'X-Application-Authorization: Bearer Token'"
h2flag="'Accept: application/vnd.application.v2.1+xml'"
reqflag="DELETE"
baseurl="https://api.application.com/hardwares"
while read -r id
do
    curl --verbose -H "${h1flag}" -H "${h2flag}" -X "${reqflag}" "${baseurl}/$id" 
done < input.csv
```

An example line from above would look like the following,

```
$ curl --verbose \
  -H 'X-Application-Authorization: Bearer Token' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.application.v2.1+xml' \
  -X DELETE https://api.application.com/hardwares/1945603
```

I would suggest to use this on the `cmdline` first before running it using the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the 'do' instruction right after the 'while read id' part, instead of where it is right now.

Comment: I still get the same error even with do before assigning my temp variable.

Comment: This should be a comment.